# fromWKT - how to pull all info from source data?

Tags: arcpy, well-known-text

I have a CSV storing addresses, reference numbers, etc... and also a WKT string of boundary coordinates for each property:

[image: Source data]

The script (ammended from another user's post in 2012) sccessfully converts the CSV to a shapefile, with the spatial refeence set to EPSG- 27700:

```
# convert well known text to geometry, and compile shapes into a single feature class...
# 11/15/2012
import arcpy

File = "C:\\Users\\Team\\Documents\\Theo Laptop Folder\\Tasks\\Quick tasks\\WKTtest\\WKT_to_QGISmakealayerCSV2.csv"

# dimension the WKT string field and poly ID field...
# the field holding the WKT string...
field1 = "WKT"
# the field holding the unique ID...
field2 = "Our_ref"

# set up the empty list...
featureList = []

# set the spatial reference to a known EPSG code...
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(27700)
# iterate on table row...
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(File)
row = cursor.next()
while row:
print (row.getValue(field2))

WKT = row.getValue(field1)
# this is the part that converts the WKT string to geometry using the defined spatial reference...
temp = arcpy.FromWKT(WKT, sr)
# append the current geometry to the list...
featureList.append(temp)

row = cursor.next()

# copy all geometries in the list to a feature class...
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureList, "C:\\Users\\Team\\Documents\\Theo Laptop Folder\\Tasks\\Quick tasks\\WKTtest\\WKTShapes.shp")   

# clean up...
del row, temp, WKT, File, field1, featureList, cursor
```

This is in python 2.7 language fyi. (I'd love this in 3.6 if possible...)

Now when I drag the newly created shapefile into Arc it all looks great, but the fields from the CSV aren't carried across...

[image: WKT to shapefile]

How can I ammend the code to include all the original string fields from the CSV?

I know a workaround that involves Joining the source csv to the output shapefile, but I'm sure there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: I think you're lucky to get that, the geometries are being exported as an array of geometries.. I would create a feature class and use an insert cursor personally but I 'spose if it works why fight it. If you can join then have a read of join field http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm which permanently joins the tables - it would be the quickest way.

Comment: Please note though GIS.SE isn't a code review site, generally a question should be about a specific problem you're encountering with a minimum block of code and error messages.

Comment: As a `QGIS` and `ogr2ogr` user, I'd be very surprised if `ArcGIS` would not support such a basic feature, importing csv with wkt geometries?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I see, I'd love to know how to use an insert cursor and understand how they work!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're going from a table to a shapefile you'll have to create a new shapefile and add each field individually. Then initiate an insert cursor for your new shapefile and a search cursor on your table. Change the WKT to a geometry object. Add all field values. Update the new feature's geometry with the `"SHAPE@"` token.

This is untested but it should point you in the right direction:

```
print "importing"
import os
import arcpy

#input csv
File = "C:\Users\e1b8\Desktop\E1B8\Outside\Book1.csv"

#create shapefile
print "creating new feature class"
outShp = "C:\\Users\\Team\\Documents\\Theo Laptop Folder\\Tasks\\Quick tasks\\WKTtest\\WKTShapes.shp"
outPath, outName = os.path.split (outShp)
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(27700)
arcpy.arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management (outPath, outName, "POLYGON",
                                           spatial_reference = sr)

#add fields
cursFlds = []
desc = arcpy.Describe (outShp)
shpFld = desc.shapeFieldName
oidFld = desc.OIDFieldName
for fld in arcpy.ListFields (File):
    if fld.name in [shpFld, oidFld]: continue
    print "adding", fld.name
    arcpy.AddField_management (outShp,
                               fld.name,
                               fld.type,
                               fld.precision,
                               fld.scale,
                               fld.length,
                               fld.alias,
                               fld.isNullable,
                               fld.required,
                               fld.domain)
    #cursor fields - add field name
    cursFlds += [fld.name]

#get wkt field index
field1 = "WKT"
wktIndex = cursFlds.index (field1)

#insert
print "iteratng csv"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (File, cursFlds) as sCurs:
    #insert cursor new shapefile
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor (outShp, cursFlds + ["SHAPE@"]) as iCurs:
        for row in sCurs:
            #get wkt string
            wkt = row [wktIndex]
            #create geometry object from wkt
            geom = arcpy.FromWKT (wkt, sr)
            #create out row
            outRow = list (row) + [geom]
            #insert row
            iCurs.insertRow (outRow)

print "created:"
print outShp
```